# What are the invariants of 2-by-2 matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}$Consider a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$. As shown in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariants_of_tensors#Principal_invariants), the principal invariants of this matrix are as follows:
$$ I_1 = \tr(A) = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3,\\
I_2 = \frac12(\tr(A)^2-\tr(A^2)) = \lambda_1\lambda_2 + \lambda_1\lambda_2 + \lambda_2\lambda_3,\\
I_3 = \det(A) = \lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3.$$

Could you please tell me whether these definitions are valid for a smaller matrix $B\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$, so that:
$$ I_1 = \tr(A) = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2,\\
I_2 =\frac 12(\tr(A)^2-\tr(A^2)) = \lambda_1\lambda_2 = \det(A),\\
I_3 = \det(A) = \lambda_1\lambda_2.$$

Comment: See also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley–Hamilton_theorem) for $2\times 2$ with Cayley-Hamilton.

Comment: Note for $2\times2$ only two of the variants are distinct

Comment: Note my edits. Writing \operatorname{tr} does not only prevent italicization, but also results in context-dependent spacing, so that for example the spaces to the right of $\operatorname{tr}$ differ in these two instances: $$ \begin{align} & \operatorname{tr} A \\ & \operatorname{tr}(A) \end{align} $$ Furthermore notice the spacing in $3\operatorname{tr}(A),$ which does not look like $3\text{tr}(A). \qquad$

Comment: You might want to investigate [Newton's Identities,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Application_to_the_characteristic_polynomial_of_a_matrix) which extends these ideas to larger matrices.  Interestingly, $\det(A)$ is not required for any of the matrix invariants, e.g. 
$$I_3 = \frac{1}{6}\Big(
    \operatorname {tr}(A)^3
 - 3\operatorname {tr}(A)\operatorname {tr}(A^2)
 + 2\operatorname {tr}(A^3)
\Big)$$ In general, for an $(n\times n)$ matrix, we have $I_n=\det(A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can easily verify that these relations are true for $2\times 2$ matrices as well.